# How to properly write and save a new Excel file?

Tags: vba, excel, scada

An application (a SCADA program) has an event that trigers every day and run a script that writes an Excel file (one for each day). The file could contain multiple sheets.

On Windows 7, with Office 2007 installed, I can write, but I can't save and neither quit the `Excel.Application`.

```
Dim objExcel as Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.WorkBooks.Add  'I think I shouldn't do this, but if not it doesn't work

Set sheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Worksheets.Add
'writing to the actual sheet...

objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs path$
objExcel.Workbooks.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

If I run the script manually (from the script editor):

- it saves
- the Excel process still runing
- When I open the Excel file (not from script), this has 2 workbooks,
  the actual and the last one from the last execution.

If I try trigger the event:

- error occurs on the line when it saves

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Wi

Comment: "The Basic Control Engine combines the power of the CIMPLICITY event handler with a Visual Basic™ compliant language, allowing you to script and program applications and routines from the simple to the complex." whatever...

Comment: I'm asking which would be the steps to: create & write a new excel, with multiple sheets, save it and close it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It's VBA, from [the manual](http://platforma.astor.com.pl/files/getfile/id/4671) - *"The Program Editor utilizes an embedded Basic language that is syntactically
compatible with **Microsoft’s Visual Basic for Applications™**. This language
provides the rich Basic command set, in addition to CIMPLICITY software
specific extensions."*

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Weird the error they posted is .Net though, must use VBA as a sub-system, either that or the codebase has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
Dim objExcel as Object
Dim sheet as Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.WorkBooks.Add

Set sheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Worksheets.Add
'writing to the actual sheet...

path$ = "path/must/use/slash/insteed/of/backslash"

objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs path$
objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Close
objExcel.Quit  
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

So the problem was the `path$` and I forgot to put `Set objExcel = Nothing`. Thats all.